# Spring JDBC giving error :"queryForObject(String, Object[], Class<String>) from the type JdbcTemplate refers to the missing type DataAccessException "

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-jdbc

I have created a method in DAO:

```
public String getUserName(int userid){
    String sql="SELECT userName from UserDetail where userid=?";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userid}, String.class);
}
```

this line: `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userid}, String.class)` is giving the following errors:

```
The method queryForObject(String, Object[], Class<String>) from the type JdbcTemplate refers to the missing type DataAccessException

Multiple markers at this line
- The type org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The method queryForObject(String, Object[], Class<String>) from the type JdbcTemplate refers to the missing type 
 DataAccessException
```

I am using spring-jdbc 4.0.0 with mysql-connector 5.1.25, commons-dbcp-1.4 and commons-pool-1.6. Could you please tell me what am I mssing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add [spring-tx jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-tx/3.0.0.RELEASE) of your spring version to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

DataAccessException is in org.springframework.transaction-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar -- include this jar in classpath.